# How can I tweet videos from an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter

How can I tweet videos from an iPhone app **programmatically** ? 
(the absence of **programmatically** caused me 3 vote downs :D)

Is there a way I can attach a video to a tweet ? Or should I upload the video somewhere else and just tweet the link ?

Any guidance in this regard is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload the video, then link it in. You can't really 'attach' anything to a tweet.

Answer (score 0):

i have same question, how to attach video to tweetsheet programmatically.  only found code for setting tweetsheet text, image, or url link.  looks like need to upload the video (eg. to amazon s3), then add video's url to tweetsheet ->

```
[tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting from my own app! :)"]

if (self.imageString) {
    [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageString]];
}

if (self.urlString) {
    [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]];
}
```

i checked the following tutorials/docs:

raywenderlich tutorial
(http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6)

appcoda tutorial
(http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-integrate-twitter-and-facebook-sharing-in-ios-6/)

apple docs
(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205)